# how to use pandas groupby to aggregate data across multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, sum

I have a pandas dataframe:

| Reference | timestamp | sub_reference | datatype_indicator | figure |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| REF1 | 2022-09-01 | 10 | A | 23.6 |
| REF1 | 2022-09-01 | 48 | B | 25.8 |
| REF1 | 2022-09-02 | 10 | A | 17.4 |
| REF1 | 2022-10-01 | 10 | A | 23.6 |
| REF1 | 2022-10-01 | 48 | B | 25.8 |
| REF1 | 2022-10-02 | 10 | A | 17.4 |
| REF2 | 2022-09-01 | 10 | A | 23.6 |
| REF2 | 2022-09-01 | 48 | B | 25.8 |
| REF2 | 2022-09-02 | 10 | A | 17.4 |
| REF2 | 2022-10-01 | 11 | A | 23.6 |
| REF2 | 2022-10-01 | 47 | B | 25.8 |
| REF2 | 2022-10-02 | 10 | A | 17.4 |
| REF3 | 2022-09-01 | 10 | A | 23.6 |
| REF3 | 2022-09-01 | 48 | B | 25.8 |
| REF3 | 2022-09-02 | 10 | A | 17.4 |
| REF3 | 2022-10-01 | 11 | A | 23.6 |
| REF3 | 2022-10-01 | 47 | B | 25.8 |
| REF3 | 2022-10-02 | 10 | A | 17.4 |

I need to group the data by 'Reference' and the month in 'timestamp' to produce an aggregated value of 'figure' for the reference/month..

I am trying the below code, but receive *TypeError: unhashable type: 'Series'*

```
dg = df1.groupby([
            pd.Grouper('reference'),
            pd.Grouper(df1['timestamp'].dt.month)
            ]).sum()
dg.index = dg.index.strftime('%B')
print(dg)
```

Comment: did the answer worked for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used the `pd.Grouper` before, but I think your issue is with how it is treating the extraction of the month.

I tried it like this:

```
>>> # add a new column for month
>>> df1["month"] = df1["timestamp"].dt.month

>>> dg = df1.groupby(by=["Reference", "month"], as_index=False).agg({"figure":sum})
>>> dg
  Reference  month  figure
0      REF1      9    66.8
1      REF1     10    66.8
2      REF2      9    66.8
3      REF2     10    66.8
4      REF3      9    66.8
5      REF3     10    66.8
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# create a year-month from teh date
# groupby and sum figure
df['month'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp']).dt.strftime('%Y-%b')
out= df.groupby(['Reference','month' ], as_index=False)['figure'].sum()

out
```

OR

```
# use assign to create month column
# group and sum figure

out= (df.assign(month=pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp']).dt.strftime('%Y-%b'))
 .groupby(['Reference','month' ], as_index=False)['figure'].sum())

out
```

```
    Reference   month   figure
0   REF1    2022-Oct    66.8
1   REF1    2022-Sep    66.8
2   REF2    2022-Oct    66.8
3   REF2    2022-Sep    66.8
4   REF3    2022-Oct    66.8
5   REF3    2022-Sep    66.8
```

Answer (score 0):

```
grouper = pd.PeriodIndex(df['timestamp'], freq='M')
df.groupby(['Reference', grouper])['figure'].sum().reset_index()
```

result:

```
    Reference   timestamp   figure
0   REF1        2022-09     66.8
1   REF1        2022-10     66.8
2   REF2        2022-09     66.8
3   REF2        2022-10     66.8
4   REF3        2022-09     66.8
5   REF3        2022-10     66.8
```

if you want change to `%B`

```
grouper = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp']).dt.strftime('%B')
df.groupby(['Reference', grouper])['figure'].sum().reset_index()
```

result:

```
    Reference   timestamp   figure
0   REF1        October     66.8
1   REF1        September   66.8
2   REF2        October     66.8
3   REF2        September   66.8
4   REF3        October     66.8
5   REF3        September   66.8
```

Comment: I tried this and the output wasn't as expected (sorry can't work out how to format the table in this reply)  timestamp
0 September
1 September
2 September
1440 October
1441 October

Comment: draw your desired output by example and edit question.